# Filter json output in azure synapse-pipeline?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm creating a Pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics using the synapse pipeline to get the content of a Rest-API call. Before the call I have to get the bearer token. While using the web activity to get the bearer token for an Rest-API Call, I get the bearer token in a format like `{"access_token":"Sample-Bearer-Token","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":999999}`.

I would like to only get the content from `"access_token"`, in order to pass it for the REST-API Call. It seems like I can get the whole output of the web activity with `@activity('Web1').output` but how can I filter the json output in a synapse-pipeline to only get the bearer token?

Best regards and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference key name value pairs in json using the dot syntax, so something like this should work for you:

```
@activity('Web1').output.access_token
```

You could assign this to a variable using the [Set Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) activity for testing or just use it directly in the next activity.